# Why constant metric tensor allows finite displacement

Tags: metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

Consider as space coordinates $q_1,q_2,q_3$ why if the metric tensor is not constant in space $q_1, q_2, q_3$ can't be considered a displacement vector? And why vice versa, a constant metric tensor in space allows $q_1, q_2, q_3$ to be considered as a displacement vector?

Comment: you mean that the metric tensor is not constant in space $\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial t}\neq 0$ ?

Comment: I mean $G=G(q_1,q_2,q_3)$